# Error Requiring Bootstrap-Sass in Compass Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems, sass, compass

I have installed bootstrap-sass through the gem and imported into my compass project. However when I recompile the project or watch it I get the following errors:

```
error sass/core.scss (Line 9: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-custom.
Load paths:
  Compass::SpriteImporter
  /var/www/html/design/sass
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.3/assets/stylesheets
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.3/assets/stylesheets)
    write css/ie.css
    write css/print.css
```

However when I go to the directories in the trace there are contents within them:

```
jayden@localhost:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems$ l
total 60K
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root 4.0K Jan 27 21:56 autoprefixer-rails-5.0.0.3/
drwxr-xr-x. 7 root 4.0K Jan 27 21:56 bootstrap-sass-3.3.3/
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root 4.0K Jan 22 21:50 chunky_png-1.3.3/
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root 4.0K Jan 22 22:04 compass-1.0.3/
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root 4.0K Jan 22 21:50 compass-core-1.0.3/
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root 4.0K Jan 22 21:50 compass-import-once-1.0.5/
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root 4.0K Jan 27 21:56 execjs-2.2.2/
drwxr-xr-x. 7 root 4.0K Jan 22 22:04 ffi-1.9.6/
drwxrwxr-x. 4 root 4.0K Jan 23 18:09 font-awesome-sass-4.2.2/
drwxr-xr-x. 9 root 4.0K Jan 27 21:56 json-1.8.2/
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root 4.0K Jan 22 21:50 multi_json-1.10.1/
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root 4.0K Jan 22 21:50 rb-fsevent-0.9.4/
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root 4.0K Jan 22 22:04 rb-inotify-0.9.5/
drwxr-xr-x. 8 root 4.0K Jan 22 21:54 sass-3.4.10/
drwxr-xr-x. 8 root 4.0K Dec  3 10:50 sass-3.4.9/
```

I have the exact same problem as well with Fontawsome. If someone could help it would be greatly appreciated!

Config.rb:

```
 require 'compass/import-once/activate'
#require 'font-awesome-sass'
require 'bootstrap-sass'
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
#css_path = "production_css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "img"
javascripts_dir = "js"

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
# line_comments = false


# If you prefer the indented syntax, you might want to regenerate this
# project again passing --syntax sass, or you can uncomment this:
# preferred_syntax = :sass
# and then run:
# sass-convert -R --from scss --to sass sass scss && rm -rf sass && mv scss sass
```

Comment: What does your config.rb look like?

Comment: @cimmanon Ive updated my question with the config. Thanks!